# Not able to display images in UIWebView from resource folder in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

In my project i want to display the Images in resources file in the webview

i am placing that content in html page and showing in web view.
in my body content having some images it is taking url like this
 the problem is the image is not displaying in webview only question mark image is displaying in webview?

this is the code i written for this

NSURL *resourcePathURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] isDirectory:YES];

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:contentString baseURL:resourcePathURL];

[resourcePathURL release];
```

i am taking image names like this "Asparagus-with-Shallots.png"
i am taking different dimenssion to each images 120*150,130*230 like this 
   '$''$'

```
        '$'<p><img src=”Tiramisu.png”/><br>a computer file consisting solely '$'
```

'$' of printable characters from a recognized character set.

*4 servings*

**Cream'$' '$'Filling**
1 cup mascarpone cheese (8 ounces) 
1 a computer file consisting solely'$' 
'$'of printable characters from a recognized character set!

*For the syrup:'$'
'$'* '$'

I am attaching a image, I am getting the image displaying like in image getting from resource folder

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go through this post: [iPhone Dev: UIWebView baseUrl to resources in Documents folder not App bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926117/iphone-dev-uiwebview-baseurl-to-resources-in-documents-folder-not-app-bundle). Looks like your question is answered here.