# UIWebView - Load a local .html file with linked resources

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview, document

I don't know how many forums I have already read, but I really don't know why it doesn't work!

I have an iPhone Application and I would like to show a Epub book to my user.

The user can read it online, otherwise he can download it into the Application Documents directory to read it afterwards.

I build this folder structure same like the online version and saved it into the document folder "frontend".

I ALSO can read this maintaine .HTML file, BUT the linked JS / CSS and HTML files does not work.

So I have some screenshots. I don't know, why the javascript cannot access to the .html docs.

[offline version - saved into the filesystem "document folder"](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bih4m22br0lcbpw/Bildschirmfoto%202012-11-08%20um%2012.14.37.png)

[online version - directly from server - it's ok!](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tvrn0gnsgpqt4g/Bildschirmfoto%202012-11-08%20um%2012.16.49.png)

I hope you could give me some hints.

Comment: If you are doing a native app, you can use the 'bridge' described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9640486/792677 (intercepting the webView load requests and processing them outside of the webView).

Comment: I use [webView loadRequest...] to show my .html from documents. This .html has also ref links with relative paths to css / JS and other html docs. But it does not working...

Comment: Do you mean the js and css are not working at all ? Then you might find useful the link in the second answer of the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733883/loading-javascript-into-a-uiwebview-from-resources

Comment: I think the problem is, that my html structure isn't in the NSBundle. I generate it dynamically if the user need it. It will store in the document directory, so this method does not work.

Comment: I have got this folder structure in the applications documents folder:        Application->Document->mlib->script->xxx.js                                   If my index.html has been loaded into the web view, is it possible to load a .js relatively from he index.html???

Comment: Hi i changed my Code. As you said I stored my index.html and my javascripts into the mainBundle. Like this: NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"offlineEpub" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"WWW"]];
    [webViewEpub loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];          Can I link from this index.html to the resources like other .html files from document directory?

Answer (score 4):

Simply write the code

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"offlineEpub" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[webView loadHTMLString:content baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

The main thing is provide base url as your mainBundle or documents directory.

Answer (score 4):

After much fiddling around and reading a lot of answers, here is my simple consolidated solution:

**1) Make sure all your bundle resources are unique---directories get flattened**

It is super frustrating, but if you had directories "About/index.html" and "Home/index.html", one of the last "index.html" to get copied into the bundle will overwrite the previous.

**2) JavaScript files will be in the wrong Build Phase**

In Xcode click on your project, then click on your app target, then click on Build Phases. Notice the JavaScript files will wrongly be in Compiled Sources: move JS files into Copy Bundle Resources.

**3) Use UIWebView's loadRequest:**

Don't load from a string. Use an NSURL instead.

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *url = [mainBundle URLForResource:@"some_page" withExtension:@"html"];
NSURLRequest *urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Assuming you create an IBOutlet defined like:
// @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *wv;
[self.wv loadRequest:urlReq];
```