# offline product presentation for ipad

Tags: ios, cordova, web-applications, offline

i have to create a product presentation tool that runs offline on an ipad.
i have a program wirtten in c# to create a presentation and this program has an export function, this export function creates a whole little homepage (only html and javascript) with the product slider - everything works fine, also the online presentation is perfect.

but the capital problem is, how could i run this offline on the ipad?

what i already tried: 
- put the scripts to dropbox and tried to start index.html on ipad (the local links doesnt work)
- i tried to chache the whole page, but that was too much for caching..

there is also one solution i would prefer -> phonegap, but there i see the problem with creating the app... the c# programm should prepare everything, so the clients should take this exported file/files or direcotry and but it anywhere and the ipad should run this presentation offline.

thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a simple app with UIWebView inside and load your local resources into this UIWebView.

Here are some similar questions on how to make it:

[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420925/load-resources-from-relative-path-using-local-html-in-uiwebview)

[Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733883/loading-javascript-into-a-uiwebview-from-resources)

[Third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289589/uiwebview-load-a-local-html-file-with-linked-resources)

The way your clients are able to add the presentation files might be using [iTunes File Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201301). And you can get these files from [Documents directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907381/what-is-the-documents-directory-nsdocumentdirectory)

Hope this will help.