# How to call a js file with html file

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Can i inject js file into html file? 
I have tried  [Loading javascript into a UIWebView from resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733883/loading-javascript-into-a-uiwebview-from-resources) but i am unable to load js file

lib.js

```
function alertMeWithMyCustomFunction(text) {
    alert(text+' -> in lib.js');
}
```

Test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MathJax</title>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"lib.js\" />
        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"MathJaxUnpacked/MathJax.js\"></script>
        <script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [[\"$\",\"$\"],[\"\\(\",\"\\)\"]]}});</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <a href=\"javascript:alertMeWithMyCustomFunction('I am');\">External js test</a>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href=\"javascript:alert('Works!')\">Test Javascript Alert</a>


        <br>
            <h1>MathJax Test</h1>
        <br>
        <p>Here the HTML is dynamically inserted using loadHTMLString in a UIWebView, and the JavaScript and image are referenced from the resources of the application.</p>
        <br>
        <p>$$\\int_x^y f(x) dx$$</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <img src=\"images/test.jpg\">
    </body>
</html>
```

Code in viewdidload

```
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    _webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
 [_webview loadHTMLString:html
                    baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                             [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];


    [self setView: _webview];
```

where i am doing wrong? I don't have a folder structure the file are in projects default folder structure it self.
[image] when i click on links nothing happens

Comment: you have to call javascript function

Comment: I guess your js file is not loaded for some reason, because of a bad reference issue. Where is your html file located? Do both html and js files located on the same place? Did you try using Simulator with Safari's developer inspector to look for javascript errors/file loading problems?

Comment: both the files are in same location

Answer (score 0):

heck the UIWebView method called:

stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script;

```
NSString *result = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(@"alert('test')
```

Comment: it doesn't work since i am using the script directly in html file