# I want to load the html content including java script in WKWebview

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, wkwebview

```
self.nflWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.nflWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.nflWebView.opaque = NO;
[[self nflWebView] setDelegateViews: self];
self.nflWebView.tag = 10000;
[self.nflWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSBundle mainBundle].bundleURL];
[self.view addSubview:self.nflWebView];
```

I have also try the another things:

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script
{
NSLog(@"stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString");
NSLog(@"script :%@",script);
__block NSString *resultString = nil;
__block BOOL finished = NO;
WKWebView *obj_wkwebview=[[WKWebView alloc]init];
    [obj_wkwebview evaluateJavaScript:script completionHandler:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            if (result != nil) {
                resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"evaluateJavaScript error : %@", error);
        }
        finished = YES;
    }];

    while (!finished)
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }

return resultString;
}
```

its give the error.

```
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo=0x170c788c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}
```

simple html content is loading successfull but html with javascript is not loading.

I have done a lot of Googling but not success. Please Suggest me if u have any another approach to do this thing.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This link will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733883/loading-javascript-into-a-uiwebview-from-resources

Comment: u r asking ...u want to load ur javascreept page in ur web view...?

Comment: @PiyushPatel this link using uiwebview not in wkwebview.

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR i have a html that is included java script when ever i have load this html the html content loading successfull does not show the java script content. its show only html content.