# How to use javascript code in objective C in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I have a webview in which i have to open online chat when it is loads. I have a javascript code for the online chat . I'm confused that how can i use it. I have tried to open apple website its working fine , but how can i use javascript code in Objective c. I'm quite new to language and this is first time i'm using this. I have added javascript code in a folder and add it to the resources folder in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
NSString *scriptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"JavaScript" ofType:@"js"];
NSString *scriptContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:scriptURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[wkWebView evaluateJavaScript: scriptContent completionHandler:^(id _Nullable content, NSError * _Nullable error)
 {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
         return;
     }

     NSLog(@"Content: %@",content);
 }];
```

Comment: Here is [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) doc.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [the apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/JavaScriptFromObjC.html). It will help you more.

Here is [the best example](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/calling-objective-c-function-from-javascript-in-ios-applications/) to use script in webView.

This is something that you can use into your code:

```
NSString *path;
NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
path = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"first" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *instructionsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:instructionsURL]];

 NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myFunction()"];
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction()"];
```

Comment: I have html file and js file in my project resources folder. @Nirmalsinh

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733883/loading-javascript-into-a-uiwebview-from-resources

Comment: Check above answer. It will help you.