# using UIWebView with images not included in NSBundle but that have been downloaded

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I have downloaded a couple images and I need to view them in and print them from a UIWebView but I cannot seem to get the path correct to get the images to display in the UIWebView.

Anyone done this successfully?

My images are download to a path Documents/MyFolder/MyImage.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: just copy the html you want to display to the documents directory and use relative file paths.

I just tested this and it works. First copy your assets into the user document directory. Here just one image as an example. You could copy a whole directory, etc.

```
NSURL *documentsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *imageURL = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.gif"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[imageURL path]]) {
    NSString *bundleImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"gif"];
    if (bundleImage) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:bundleImage toPath:[imageURL path] error:nil];
    }
}
```

Also copy your html pages (this just shows how I set up the test):

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<html>Here is a picture: <br>"
"<img src=\"image.gif\" height=100 width=100> "
"</html>";

NSURL *mainPageURL = [documentsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.html"];
NSLog(@"%@", mainPageURL);
[htmlString writeToURL:mainPageURL atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Finally load the page - works like a charm.

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:mainPageURL]];
```

A caveat about running this in the **iOS Simulator**. The URL is different on a Mac. In short, you have to use the format `@"file:/.../"`and replace all slashes `/` with double slashes `//`, and all spaces with `%20`. More on this in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926117/iphone-dev-uiwebview-baseurl-to-resources-in-documents-folder-not-app-bundle) question.

Comment: I have tried every combination of relative path I could think of in my app with no luck.