# uiwebview loading local html file - strange Webkit error

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, webkit

I am trying to run the following code in my app (ref: [iPhone Dev: UIWebView baseUrl to resources in Documents folder not App bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926117/iphone-dev-uiwebview-baseurl-to-resources-in-documents-folder-not-app-bundle))

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];

NSString *HTMLData = @"<h1>Hello this is a test</h1><img src="sample.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" />";
[webView loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:
[NSURL URLWithString: 
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//",imagePath]
]];
```

It works perfectly well in a separate project. But when I try it in my existing project, I get the following on the console, followed b a blank webView :

```
 *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSRangeException> *** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]
```

Any ideas on where shall I look for. in my code?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

So sorry ... there was a problem in `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`

My fault, was carried away with the weird webkit message

Comment: You should say what the problem was so that people who encounter this error in the future can have a hint on how to fix it.

Comment: Also, re-read the docs about NSString's path additions and NSURL - it's a very bad approach that you use for creting the URL.

Comment: As @CarlVeazey said... you should say what the problem was and how you solved it... i´m facing an issue like this right now... and this answer doesn´t help me at all.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
 NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
 NSString *strHTML = @"<html><h1>Hello this is a test</h1><img src="sample.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="100" /></html>";
 [webView loadHTMLString:strHTML baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: This error occurred for me when Crittercism was enabled. Sending the bundlePath as the baseURL fixed the issue for me.