# Display image in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview

I have a static screen that I want to display the text content include image in UITextView but when I drag the ImageView, it is on the top of TextView and I want image in textview in case I want to scroll it all together.Thank in advance.

Comment: We can help you better if you tell us [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: I built the interface of static text and image. I use TextView to display but my content have Photo and Content, but I for the image I use imageview to display, so these two control are different layer mean that ImageView on top and TextView is under. I want to display image and text in TextView. Can I?

Answer (score 5):

`UITextView` is for displaying textual content. If you would like to mix text with images, the most common solution is to use [`UIWebView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), pre-define a simple HTML template, and then insert the text and an image reference into the template.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1926975/335858) to an answer that explains how to use `UIWebView`'s `loadHTMLString:` method.

Comment: @user1628083 You are welcome! Try it out and see if it works for you. If it does, consider accepting the answer by clicking the outline of a check mark next to it to let others know that you are not looking for an improved answer, and to earn a brad-new badge on Stack Overflow.