# Add image on UITextView with custom spacing and text

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitextview, overlay, xcode4.5

I want to add Image on text view and want proper spacing as shown in screenshot.
[image: Its A screenshot as I want as per design:]

I have tried to add image on textview but I m having problem in placing text as per requirement.
Please provide me help regarding same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SWIFT:

```
var exclusionPath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height))

textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths  = [exclusionPath]
textView.addSubview(imageView)
```

Answer (score 9):

Add the below code after defining textView and imageView.

```
import CoreText.Framework

UIBezierPath *exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];

textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths  = @[exclusionPath];

[textView addSubview:imageView];
```

to have a clear idea on core text tutorial see [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50151/text-kit-tutorial)

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're having is that the image you put in your question is not using a `UITextView`.

The way this is done is to use `Text Kit` and render the text manually onto a view.

By doing this you can (in iOS7) specify a `CGPath` that the text "wraps" around.

There is a 2013 WWDC video "Introducing Text Kit" that you can watch [here](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/).

That shows how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

as par my suggestion you could use `UIWebview` instead of `TextView` for Doing this task use `loadHTMLString` here it is a [example of loading local fines in `UIWebview`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926117/iphone-dev-uiwebview-baseurl-to-resources-in-documents-folder-not-app-bundle/1926975#1926975) please take a look this and impliment as par you required

Answer (score 3):

@Fogmeister is correct, however if you want to do something a bit less complicated by using the default RICH TEXT with IMAGE capabilities now available in iOS 7 using just NSAttributedString then take a look at this [link](http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/implementing-rich-text-with-images-on-os-x-and-ios/).

You won't be able to support text wrapping - use Pages for that - but for simple note taking this might do.