# Set Image inline with text to UITextView in Objective C

Tags: ios, uiimage, uitextview

I want to add image inline with text to UITextView just like below screenshot

[image]

I have try using `NSTextAttachment` and `NSAttributedString` but it put only one line before & after the image.

Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: It may Helpful:

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010035/how-to-add-image-and-text-in-uitextview-in-ios

Comment: I have tried this one before posting this question but it is not working for my requirement. And i have also mention about this in my question

Comment: That's a nice image. Can you post the text as well, just in case the image link dies? Also, can you edit the various things you've tried and why they don't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just use 'UIBezierPath'

For example,

```
txtvHtmlString.text = @“your long text…….”;

imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 100, 152, 128)];

imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smily.png"];     
imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
[txtvHtmlString addSubview:imgView];
```

Then don't forget to update bezierpath in viewDidLayoutSubviews if your text is updated.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    UIBezierPath *exclusionPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imgView.frame];
    txtvHtmlString.textContainer.exclusionPaths  = @[exclusionPath];
}
```