# Output specific images when user taps the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I want to output a image when a user taps on the keyboard. Let's say the user taps A on the keyboard in a UITextView. Instead of outputting the normal A, I want to output the picture of an Ape.
If a user taps "S" I want to output the image of a sun. Is this possible with out having to make a customized keyboard?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010035/how-to-add-image-and-text-in-uitextview-in-ios follow this answer it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides creating a custom keyboard yourself, there isn't really a *neat* method to getting an image output.

One thing you could do is program Swift to **automatically recognise the letter input** and **display an image over or replacing the letter** as a result.

To do this, *assign a variable to your editable UITextView or UITextField*. If you are using XCode you can do this by **control-dragging the text field into your code** and it will automatically create a `weak var`, but you can change the strength in the pop up box that appears.

Since you now have a variable, there are two options as to how you display the image. One way is *rather boring and will clutter your code*, but essentially involves this, which I have simplified for the purposes of demonstration:

```
if UITextInput == a {
// add image
}
```

You would have to **repeat this for every letter** of the alphabet.

Or you could create a **dictionary** in which each letter corresponds to each image, and find a way to cycle through them, depending on the user's input. Even though this is harder to program for a newbie, it makes the code much neater and quicker.

This is the link to the *official Apple documentation* on dictionaries:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113

However, since I assume you are programming an app for the younger market, I would recommend creating a **custom keyboard** as it will be *easier* in the long run.

Hope this helps,
***will***

Comment: Yeah I probably thought so. Okay thank you! 
I am pretty new to programming, so could you give me any idea, how such a syntax would look? :-)

Comment: Hey William. Thank you so much for your help. Appreciate it. I have upvoted, even tho it will first take effect when I have 15 in reputation :(.

Comment: Hey Will,

I have another question if you have time to answer. Where should I place my code? if UITextInput == a {
// add image
}

I tried both in the view did load and in some functions like textViewDidChangeSelection textViewDidBeginEditing but nothing happens. I tried to NSLog("a") just to check. Do you have any suggestions?