# How can I add image in UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitextview

I'm making a note taking app but I ran into trouble.

I want to put a image in **UITextView**. I used **NSAttributedString** to put the image in **UITextView** but when I put image from the imagepicker, the image size is too big like this

[image]

I want to make it like the apple notes app

[image: image2]

How can I figure that?

```
   let images = selectedImage
   let attachment = NSTextAttachment()

   attachment.image = images

   let attString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)

   textView.textStorage.insertAttributedString(attString, atIndex: textView.selectedRange.location)
```

Answer (score 6):

This might be helpful to you

```
let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 300))
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "before after")
let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
textAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "sample_image.jpg")!

let oldWidth = textAttachment.image!.size.width;

let scaleFactor = oldWidth / (textView.frame.size.width - 10); //for the padding inside the textView
textAttachment.image = UIImage(CGImage: textAttachment.image!.CGImage, scale: scaleFactor, orientation: .Up)
var attrStringWithImage = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)
attributedString.replaceCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(6, 1), withAttributedString: attrStringWithImage)
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
self.view.addSubview(textView)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works!! but when I save **NSAttributedString** to **NSUserDefaults** and when I load again the image size is big again!!

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30417310/2564702

Comment: hi, can you explain why using NSMakeRange(6, 1)?