# How to align an image embedded in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift

Because of my app logic I need to present some text with images within `UITextView`. It's not a problem to embed an image (working solution is given, for example, here [How to add image and text in UITextView in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010035/how-to-add-image-and-text-in-uitextview-in-ios)). But I absolutely have no clue how to align the image. I try to set attributes

```
var attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString!
let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)            

textAttachment.image = image
let attrStringWithImage = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)

let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
let attrs = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style]

attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attrStringWithImage)
let text = NSAttributedString(string: myText, attributes: attrs)
attributedString.append(text)

myTextView?.attributedText = attributedString
```

but it doesn't influence on image. The text is aligned good, but the image always get stuck to the left edge of the view.
How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you want to allign image?

Comment: I'd like to have it at the center of the superview

Comment: Check my answer,might it will help you.

Comment: @Swift_Guru, your answer could be applicable for some cases. One can rescale an image to make it width equal to superview width and the image will be centred automatically. But in my case I'd like to save original size of the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
var attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString!
    let textAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
    let image = UIImage(named: yourImage)

    textAttachment.image = image

    textAttachment.image = UIImage(cgImage: (textAttachment.image?.cgImage)!, scale: 20, orientation: UIImageOrientation.left)
    let attrStringWithImage = NSAttributedString(attachment: textAttachment)

    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.alignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
    let attrs = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style]

    attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attrStringWithImage)
    let text = NSAttributedString(string: yourText, attributes: attrs)
    attributedString.append(text)

    txtView?.attributedText = attributedString
```

You can change orientation and scale as per your need using this code.