# Right way to make a list with images inside a tableview cell SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uistackview

I currently have a UITableView in which each cell contains a list of users. I currently have it setup using a UITextView and line break after each name. I then set the cell height accordingly to how many people are in the group.This is working great but now I want to add profile pictures by each use. Here are two possible solutions I have come up with.

1. A tableview inside each table view cell
2. Using a method like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010035/how-to-add-image-and-text-in-uitextview-in-ios/30417310#30417310) in order to add the image in as text and keep the current textview. I believe this would be the better/ more efficient option.

Which method of these two or other option would be the right way/ or most efficient way of going about doing this.

**UPDATE** : I am trying to implement a solution from below here is what I have tried but I am seeing nothing when running

ADDING STACK VIEW IN STORYBOARD 
[image]

CREATING USER VIEW CLASS

```
import UIKit

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
class UserView: UIStackView {
    var name: String?
    var image: UIImage? // OR var imageName: String?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        axis = .vertical

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        let nameLabel = UILabel()
        nameLabel.text = name

        addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        addArrangedSubview(nameLabel)
    }
}
```

CODE IN CELL FOR ROW AT INDEX PATH

```
        cell.mainStackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.cellColor.frame.width, height: cell.cellColor.frame.height)

        for i in 0..<joinedArray.count {
            let user = UserView()
            user.name = joinedArray[i]
            cell.mainStackView.addArrangedSubview(user)
        }
```

Comment: What is the largest user count you want to support in your list?

Comment: Maybe the cap would be around 20

Comment: Do not show pictures of code. Show _code_.

Comment: @matt Thank you I have updated accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer UIStackView inside a UITableViewCell and UIStackView as a subview for each user entry

Something like below mentioned

```
class UserView: UIStackView {
    var name: String?
    var image: UIImage? // OR var imageName: String?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        axis = .vertical

        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        let nameLabel = UILabel()
        nameLabel.text = name

        addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        addArrangedSubview(nameLabel)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more how I would implement this into my project, I don't really understand how to use it. Thank you, I appreciate the response.

Comment: @user6520705 Add UIStackView (ie, mainStackView) in your TableViewCell.
Now add UserView UIStackView into mainStackView programmatically for each user

Comment: In storyboard i added a stack view to my cell. Then I created a class UserView. In my cellforrowatindexpath I loop through my array of users and for each one create a new UserView and do mainstackview.append the new UserView but when I build and run I do not see anything

Comment: @user6520705 If it is still not resolved, here is the complete solution
https://gist.github.com/Satish/f973732730a24e08a4dd274d86c9e2d2

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a `UITableView` inside a `UITableViewCell`, you could try to put a `UICollectionView` in a `UITableViewCell`. Technically it's the same but with the collection view you get more versatility in the way you can have your images displayed in different layouts (assuming that each `UICollectionViewCell` takes a `UIImageView` for each respective image). Ash Furrow has a really nice [blog post](https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/) on this as well as the respective [GitHub rep](https://github.com/ashfurrow/Collection-View-in-a-Table-View-Cell).